# Should the more specific tag or less specific tag be removed when both are used?

Tags: discussion, tags

Earlier today I posted a question (I've since deleted it since I figured out my own answer and it was a silly oversight) with the tags "Laravel" and "Laravel-5"

Someone edited my tags shortly after I posted and removed the Laravel tag citing it as "redundant" but I feel like if anything, the more specific tag should have been removed... Personally I have "Laravel" in my favorites, but not all the individual versions, so I wouldn't have seen my own question while browsing my favorite tags.

I imagine it is the same with most people. So is it not appropriate to just have *both* tags on my post to capture both groups? And if it isn't appropriate, then should the more or less specific tag be chosen?

Comment: Both tags are appropriate. The editor was incorrect.

Comment: @TinyGiant Okay, thank you! I'd assumed as much. I didn't check at the time, but is it possible for me to undo his edit? Or I just re-edit myself and add it back?

Comment: You can go to the revision history by clicking the "edited <relative time>" link at the bottom of the post in the middle, then clicking "rollback on the revision previous to the edit.

Comment: PS in your favorites, you can add a tag with a wildcard to include related tech, like: `Laravel*`, which will show you all tags starting with: **Laravel**, and if you're not interested in any of the specific child tags that get included, you can add them to your **Ignored Tags** list.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

**You were correct to use both the general and the version-specific tags** when your question is version-specific or when you can only use a specific version.

As you rightly anticipated, people often express interest in a tag by subscribing to the general tag but not each of the version-specific tags.  This is natural and as it should be.

A related caution is that you should generally *not* tag a question with multiple version-specific tags.  If your question transcends versions, just use the general tag.

Comment: Unfortunately this works against people who specifically want to ignore/block certain tags.  For example, I do not use Python or a whole slew of programming languages that come up often in QA/automation.  I block Python, but the various flavors still come through because I haven't blocked every possible variant of the word.  Same is true of a lot of other tags I want to ignore, but can't because of the multiple flavors.  I realize that this is the price (at least for now) that we must pay, but I wish the ignore/block had additional logic to reduce clutter.

Comment: I haven't tried blocking, but doesn't @kjhughes advice *support* what you want to do?  If you ask to block `python`, you'd block the posts that followed his advice.

Comment: @BillHileman I'm not sure what you mean by "flavors" but you can ignore, say, `python*` and eliminate all tags that begin with `python`...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I was not aware that the ignore tags option accepted wildcards, thanks. That does help.  By flavors, Python might not have been the best example, but there are programming languages that seem to have countless variations, not only in version number but it other wordings, but they do probably all start with the same thing.  I just won't be able to use "r*" to ignore the R language or "c*" to ignore variations of the C language  :)

Comment: @BillHileman That's a perennial problem, to be sure. There have been a number of requests to create a "tag hierarchy" over the years so that one could, say, ignore "R and all its subtags". These have not fared well due to the complexity and maintenance overhead.

Comment: @BillHileman why is this “against” people who want to block? This answer suggests that the general tag should always be present, so blocking the general tag should work then, shouldn’t it?

Comment: @Holger I see your point... I'm not sure how I missed that.  As long as one blocked tag is in the list it will block the entire post - I was thinking the other way around for some reason.