# Should JavaFX-specific questions be tagged with [java] as well?

Tags: discussion, tags

(Forgive me if there is a duplicate question on this already; the closest I could find in my search was a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368955/should-the-more-specific-tag-or-less-specific-tag-be-removed-when-both-are-used) that doesn't quite apply.)

If a user is asking a question that is very specific to the JavaFX API, is the [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) tag necessary?

I have seen this tag added to several questions that deal specifically with JavaFX API (and would not be answerable without JavaFX knowledge), but I don't think that is always appropriate.

If a Java developer that is not familiar with JavaFX is searching for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions, they would need to manually filter out or ignore the [javafx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx) tag in order to get relevant results.

---

I understand there has been significant discussion on whether the "broader" or "specific" tags (or both) should be used, but in this case I feel JavaFX is both the broad and specific, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Is the question about the Java programming language? If so, then you should use the tag. If it's *only* about the framework, then you don't need it. It's a judgment call, obviously. That's why we allow editors to retag.

Comment: Depends, considering you can also [use JavaFX in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavafx%5D+%5Bkotlin%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0)

Comment: It shouldn't technically be necessary. It is probably in your own best interest to put the question under the eyes of people actually interested in JavaFX which means they have the tag on their watch list. If you tag something with Java, you're opening the flood gates.

Comment: @Gimby Java programmers not interested in JavaFX can easily ignore the tag and/or exclude it from search results.