# "The spreadsheet tag should only be used if a more specific tag does not apply"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag has a curious instruction in its usage guidance (emphasis mine):

> Use this tag for questions about spreadsheet apps, plug-ins, libraries, etc., **where no more specific tag exists**. A spreadsheet presents tabular data sets arranged in rows and columns, typically with tools for capturing, analyzing, and collaborating on that data. Each cell may contain alphanumeric text, numeric values, or formulas.

The tag wiki similarly begins like this:

> ***Note***: The [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag should only be used if a more specific tag does not apply to the question.

This seems weird and unhelpful to me, for two reasons:

- It's inconsistent with [how we handle version tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368955/1709587) (where our policy is that even if a more specific tag, like [python-3.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.7), belongs on a question, you should still include the more general tag, like [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), as well).
- If I were to follow the [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag, it would almost certainly be because I wanted to see all questions about spreadsheets. Instead limiting the tag to the (rather arbitrary) intersection of abstract package-agnostic spreadsheet questions and questions about spreadsheet packages that are too obscure for us to have a tag for them seems to me like a pointless nuisance for everybody who interacts with the tag.

Like a lot of tag usage guidance, these instructions were introduced by an edit that gave no indication at all of the motivation behind them. I really don't have a clue why the editor thought this was a good idea. They haven't been active for a few weeks, so I can't (immediately) ask them.

Meanwhile, *right now* an anonymous user is proposing edits to [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) questions that - among other, less controversial changes - remove this tag, citing the usage guidance. For the reasons above, I'm inclined to remove the guidance altogether; I think it's pointless and harmful. But I worry I'm missing something.

Is there a good reason for this guidance to stay?

Comment: Probably added by someone that got annoyed after seeing a lot of [tag:excel] + [tag:spreadsheet] questions. Imo adding this tag to Excel/Google Sheets/etc. questions is pointless, even if they are about spreadsheets, because hey, a question about spreadsheet software probably is about spreadsheets. Perhaps it's a candidate for burnination?

Comment: @ErikA Given that spreadsheet programs in practice seem to have heavily overlapping syntax, I can imagine finding it useful - if I were an expert in spreadsheets - to just follow the [spreadsheet] tag and see a stream of spreadsheet-related questions involving different packages. Having to follow or search for all spreadsheet program tags instead (I know of at least 3 in modern use - Microsoft Excel, Google Sheets, and Apple Numbers - but assume there are more) sounds annoying to me.

Comment: Meh, we're not SuperUser. Programming for Excel (VBA), Google Sheets (Apps Script) and Apple Numbers (AppleScript) are pretty different. The SuperUser/simple formula aspects are common, but that's off-topic here. I'm pretty knowledgeable about VBA myself, but wouldn't have a clue what to do in AppleScript or Apps Script. And even the complex formulas (mainly lookups) have a lot of different quirks between spreadsheet programs.

Comment: @ErikA Hmm. You have made a reasonable case, then, that this tag is pointless and deserving of burnination. That leaves me unsure what to do with its Wiki and usage guidance, though. If we *don't* burninate the tag, should the guidance I quote above remain? I'm still inclined to think the answer is "no, we should remove that guidance", since I can still imagine a (perhaps niche) audience of general spreadsheet enthusiasts finding the tag useful who would benefit from the guidance's removal, but I can't yet see any way that having the guidance makes things *better* for anybody.

Comment: I'd be in favor of a _don't use this tag at all_ guidance, that's previously been added to some tags without consulting the community at all but perhaps formally posting a burninate request is better. I probably have some time to properly write one up in the next few days, currently sort-of busy (commenting while some analyses are running, but that's not enough time to write up a proper post).

Comment: @ErikA Fair enough. In that case, I'll do nothing, and leave it in your hands for you to handle in a few days.

Comment: I've been accepting these edits, especially since they're adding more useful, specific tags to the question.