# Stop the spread of [spreadsheet]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag is currently in an awkward position. In [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386882/7296893) meta thread, it was pointed out that the excerpt provides non-standard guidance:

> Use this tag for questions about spreadsheet apps, plug-ins, libraries, etc., where no more specific tag exists

That's not being followed, however. If we look at related tags, we see that of the 3,066 questions currently tagged with it, 1,111 are also tagged [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) (about 1/3rd), and 836 are tagged [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets). If we subtract those two, there are mostly a lot of questions left about working with Excel files, some about Google sheets even though it's not tagged, and some about working with CSV files while it's not tagged.

The far minority is about other spreadsheet software, such as OpenOffice or Apple Numbers.

While the previous post wanted the non-standard guidance removed, I'd rather see the tag burninated.

My reasons for this:

- The tag is not on-topic by default. Most questions about spreadsheets and spreadsheet programs belong on [Super User](https://superuser.com/).
- The common ground between spreadsheet programs is little, especially with regard to programming and complex formula development, exporting and importing. Different spreadsheet programs use very different file formats, APIs and integrated programming languages. The tag is too broad to be useful. While you can be an expert in specific spreadsheet programs, you can hardly be an expert in spreadsheets in general.
- When the tag is used without a specific spreadsheet program or file format, in the vast majority of cases, that's a mistake and a program or file format should've been tagged. When it's used with one, it adds no value to the question.

This tag does more harm than good in my opinion. It sees off-topic use and leads to incorrect tagging of questions, while it doesn't provide benefit at all.

---

Let's go through the criteria:

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   As outlined above (point 2 of my reasons), it's ambiguous. It doesn't describe a specific program, and spreadsheet programs are very much different.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   No, not by default. Programming for spreadsheet programs is on-topic, but so is programming for cars or boats.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No, it doesn't.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Somewhat. As said under point 1, it's ambiguous in regards to which program, but a spreadsheet is a spreadsheet, no matter the context.

---

As you can see, it unfortunately doesn't meet all points, but I consider it harmful, and *something* needs to happen because a tag with guidance that gets ignored for over half of the questions under it is a large [broken window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory) in my opinion.

---

As has been pointed out in the comments, this tag contains many questions, and since it always should include a more specific tag, my preference would be not to manually review every single question, but instead that a CM would delete the tag altogether, and we'd review the remaining untagged questions. Per [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1075408), that's 37 questions currently, so I alone could retag these, and only need a little help to close/delete the bad ones that are left untagged

The disadvantage of this approach is that we won't review every question, so won't close/delete some bad ones or add descriptive tags to some of the ones that've missed it. We could heuristically add tags when a related tag is available (e.g. [excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) to questions with [vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vba), [google-sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) for questions tagged [google-apps-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script)), but that wouldn't have my personal preference.

---

<sub>I also have a pet peeve with tags you can sort-of be an expert in but are really way too broad. I follow the [ms-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) tag, and often, questions come in tagged [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) or [database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) and get multiple answers by [sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql) experts (high-rep users following that tag, sometimes gold-badge holders) that contain invalid syntax and can never work because the concepts used (window functions, CTEs) are just unsupported. At best, the [spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spreadsheet) tag is a tag that encourages similar poor answers from experts in one spreadsheet program.</sub>

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not sure I agree with *"The tag is not on-topic by default."* Spreadsheets are programs, and nothing in our rules says that only programming paradigms where you write text in a text editor are on-topic here. I'd prefer to take an expansive view of our scope where even pure spreadsheet formula questions are considered on-topic. (I take the same perspective on questions about visual flow-chart-based programming tools like those used with Lego Mindstorms.) But *regardless* of whether we do that or not, it's arguable that this tag isn't adding value.

Comment: Spreadsheet apps are based on the same "model" but they have a lot of features that aren't supported by other spreadsheet apps including spreadsheets functions (formulas). Those questions looking help with  "standard features" as they are defined by ISO/IEC 26300 (OASIS OpenDocument Format) could use [tag:opendocument] and/or [tag:ods] instead of [tag:spreadsheet].

Comment: By the way, as well as Mark, I disagree with some question statements but I agree that [tag:spreadsheet] isn't helpful. I'm don't think that editing the tag excerpt/wiki will make it helpful.

Comment: Erik there are 3000 questions!! Are you really sure this tag (considering all other tags) are worth the effort? This is days and days of reviewing, you really think we should concentrate all this community effort on this tag? *is not helpful* according to me is not enough to justify this effort

Comment: @PetterFriberg That's open for debate. The main thing I'd like is community consensus if this is a bad tag, and if so, replace the current weird guidance with a _Do not use at all_. Imo we should not have tags that have that guidance without them being up for burnination. I'm 100% fine with this being at the end of the burnination queue, to be burned in 6-8 years if optimistic, 60-80 years if pessimistic.

Comment: I would support fixing tag guidance (either not use or add relvant program) but burniation is burniation, in this case several 100h of community work and honestly you have not convinced me that it's worth it

Comment: @PetterFriberg My point is not that the tag should be removed right now. My point is that the tag should be removed. And so should every other tag that doesn't have a valid use case. That's why I posted this request. When, how, and with how much effort is up to the team coordinating burninations, and the CMs if they want to remove it outright. I personally don't think we should have even a single tag with a _do not use_ guidance that's not up for removal, no matter how many questions or how much effort it'd take removing them. It can be last on the queue, only to remove if nothing better to do

Comment: The team is you and me and all other community members that like to join (It will not be many), this is the problem Erik. That's also why among 10k tags that are uselezz we need to concentrate our effort on those that damage the Q/A, in general I see tons of request with upvotez but few who later are willing to put in effort.. are you willing to spend 100h to fix this tag? That's what I ask my self before I upvotez or downvotez

Comment: That's what needs to be asked when prioritizing burnination requests, not when judging if a tag should stay or not. As said, this is likely low priority, and the cost/benefit analysis needs to be made at that step imo, not before it. There's more work coming in than being done, and we prioritize the worst stuff first, and keep this for probably never. If this reaches >20 votes, I won't expect it to get burninated as long as that system doesn't change, and I'm fine with that. But I want to have it in the list of stuff to burninate nonetheless, as an indicator it shouldn't be a tag.

Comment: From someone who uses "spreadsheets" often, indeed I find the `spreadsheet` tag unhelpful and sometimes misleading as each application has different modules / solutions / functionality. A further point, I've interacted with well researched solutions to questions which had no value because of lack of compatibility between `excel` and `google-sheets`. I'm strongly for doing away with `"spreadsheets"` and emphasizing usage of the exact tool.

Comment: @PetterFriberg You're essentially saying, "The trash pile on the floor has gotten too big. Let's just leave it there." To which any reasonable person would say, "No, we can't just leave the trash lying around. Let's figure out a way to clean it up." If our burn process precludes us from dealing with larger tags, we need a better burn process, not to forego burning. That should be obvious to anyone.

Comment: It would be a big burn, and with >1100 positive questions and ~1500 more with 0 score that would need manually vetted we couldn't just quickly skim through for the handful of good questions before having Shog nuke the rest from orbit; but we've done multi-thousand question tag burns before and can do it again.  If a few of us need to replace worn out close/delete buttons afterwards, it won't be the first time.

Comment: Note that CM's have a tool that essentially burns the entire tag with a click of a button (cc @PetterFriberg )

Comment: "Spreadsheets are programs" what? @MarkAmery Show me an executable that is basically a spreadsheet and doesn't use a spreadsheet editor.

Comment: @Braiam Show me a Java program which runs without a JRE; show me a BASIC program which runs without an interpreter; show me a Scratch program which runs without the learning environment, etc, etc. There's a line somewhere between "program" and "document", but it's not as simple as what environment interprets the contents, and may be context-dependent (consider PostScript for example - "script" is right there in the name, but most people will only see it as a way to export a document, not as something they would "execute").

Comment: @Braiam they have a tool to remove it from all questions (no tool will automatically review, edit or close stuff), if that is what you like to do (hence not follow the normal burnation process), maybe it should be tag differently.

Comment: @jpmc26 I can't agree more that "Yes we need better tools", not only for burnation but in general to handle the flow of bad questions on SO, however currently whether you like or not it's unrealistic with current burnation process to handle this request, yes there are other things we can do as "synonyms", "CM removal of tag" etc. but this is a different request, not a burnation request and certainly it needs some taught... If you have a few free hours why not join in on the current burnation and get a feel for it https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386580/5292302

Comment: @IMSoP: Shall I get out the BC7 compiler?

Comment: @PetterFriberg It isn't just a matter of better tools. A lot of it is a matter of values and how we apply them to generate process. One of the biggest problems is that we try to insist on individual review of every single last question, which is infeasible for tags of a certain size. While it would be ideal to deal with every problem question in a tag when we burn it, that demand is a massive hindrance on our ability to manage tags. We need to reconsider the entire process.

Comment: @jpmc26 I'm not sure we need reconsider the burnation process it is specific and the purpose is to clean up bad tags that encourage off-topic questions. In general instead I think people should suggest tag clean up, which consists of [tag:retag-request], [tag:synonym-request] etc, one need to study the bad tag and then find a good strategy that is not to review 3000 questions (if it is not the purpose), to remove the tag through these other methods instead.

Comment: For example if spreed-sheet is 95% excel, then a suggestion could be to retag the 5% and then synonym the spreed-sheet to excel... probably not the best solution in this case, another solution is to review a subset from query that are missing other tags as application and then ask for CM tag removal. This however is currently a burnation-request so the suggestion is to review'em all following that process.

Comment: @PetterFriberg [meta-tag:burninate-request] is the only process for tag removal, and "burn" is the community term for removing one. I know of no documentation of consensus otherwise. Nor do I know where you're getting the idea that it's "only to clean up bad tags that encourage off-topic questions." Any tag that's heavily misused or misunderstood and therefore unhelpful for fulfilling the purposes of tagging should be removed. If you're just splitting hairs over the fact this was tagged [meta-tag:burninate-request], then I'd say you need to bring your understanding in line with common usage.

Comment: @jpmc26 so now all tag removal  including merge, synonyms and retags is burnation? and therefore we need to change the guideline of what burnation is? The common usage is wrong according to me, most user have no clue even what it means and what effort is needed to complete it. Anyway if you like to change the guidelines, probably you should post a meta.

Comment: @PetterFriberg So, just so happen, you are having this discussion now, when I actually forc... cough cough, suggested Bhargav to explain the difference between disambiguation and burnination https://gist.github.com/Bhargav-Rao/220b47a45354dd4a796fbc6c15203ae0

Comment: @jpmc26 cc ^ my comment above

Comment: @Braiam yes probably it needs to be clarified since making other type of request (which is more difficult because you need study the tags, related tags and find a quick solution using available tools) you can quickly and easily solve certain tag problems, anyway my main reason to comment was because it was Erik's posts which I consider an excellent meta user and this time as on many others I dont agree burniation is needed, it's unnecessary work for community and probably for this tag it will take more 50 years, if you are not luck enough that Bhargav decides he like spend 10 days on it.

Comment: This is a quick example of a burnation that was declined (see timeline of post), but since request according to me was correct I suggested another way not involving community https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314454/5292302, overall if OP can find a similar way, I suggest not to tag question with burnation since that is a different process.

Comment: For what it's worth I have ping BhargavRao (the mod that has been spending tons on effort on users burnation requests) and rene (the community user that wrote the faq, in the current burnation room of ebay, https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/46712507#46712507

Comment: Title suggestion: Should we shoginate the [spreadsheet] tag?