# How to deal with incorrect tag removals

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Some users try to remove [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) from SwiftUI questions, claiming that *'It is SwiftUI, not Swift'*.

However, [SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/swiftui/) is just a Swift framework (not a separate language) and if you write an app in SwiftUI you're essentially using the Swift language.

As stated by Apple:

> With a declarative Swift syntax that’s easy to read and natural to
> write, SwiftUI works seamlessly [...]

---

That being said, in **Suggested Edits** queue I stumbled upon many retags which were **only** about removing the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag from [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) questions.

Here are some very recent examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27728485
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27749682
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27752184
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27749554
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27747181
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27741088
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27741085
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27729570
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27725833

What's more, these users keep ignoring the reject comments, like this very descriptive comment left by [Eric Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya):

> Are you aware that SwiftUI is made with Swift? You cannot discuss the
> former without discussing the latter.

As you can see, most of these edits are rejected (either by me or by high-rep / [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) gold-badge users). But if the OP (especially if a new member with 1 rep) approves the edit then it won't go to the *Suggested Edits* queue and the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag is immediately removed from the question.

What should we do here? Such suggested edits just add an extra workload for reviewers and, if not caught, made [swiftui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiftui) questions harder to track and/or answer.

---

Before posting here, I asked some of these users to refrain from removing the [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) tag, but it just didn't work:

[image]

Linked post on meta: *[Should the more specific tag or less specific tag be removed when both are used?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368955/should-the-more-specific-tag-or-less-specific-tag-be-removed-when-both-are-used)*

Comment: Flag for moderator attention, explain the situation, move on.

Comment: Trust me, moving on is the best thing to do. If that user doesn't want to understand, then they will get what they deserve (in this case, perhaps an edit ban).

Comment: @HereticMonkey Makes sense, custom flag has 500-character limit but now I can link this post in the flag.

Comment: The [tag:swift] tag states: "Use the tag only for questions about language features ... Use the\[se] tags ... for (language-agnostic) questions about the platforms or frameworks." We can discuss what this means, but it looks pretty clear. (There are also [thousands](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswiftui*%5D+-%5Bswift%5D+is%3Aq) of SwiftUI questions not marked with swift)

Comment: @0-1 "Use the tag only for questions... , **or requiring code in Swift.**" And this is all about Swift.

Comment: Looking the suggested edit history there, I'm getting concerned about all of the suggestions :( I'm surprised you get to keep the title here instead of it being changed from "How to deal.." to "How can I deal.."

Comment: What irked me the most was the amount of that user's edits that were approved by the reviewers. Most of them should have been rejected or at least improved.

Comment: Since the user is now gone and the edit history can no longer be accessed: If I remember correctly, they had about 27 suggested edits done over a period of 2 days. Most of them were comparable to the rejected ones shown above, editing tags and titles, sometimes even making the title worse. Other issues were mostly ignored. The majority of those edits were approved.

Comment: I often encounter the problem of new users approving bad edits as the OP. I even once saw an approved edit by an OP that changed the code and removed the actual error.... Sometimes we just can't control what others will do, no matter how much we discuss it on meta...

Comment: "Show me your power honey" that's somewhat terrifying.

Comment: @IanKemp I decided to disengage right there :)

Comment: What about turning some of those edit suggestion into review audits? So that those who aprove them get clearly indicated their mistake.